# solving second order non homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given a non homogeneous differential equation
$$
y''+4y = 3 \csc 2x.
$$ 
When I try to find value of the Wronskian $W(y_{1},y_{2}),$ the result is zero.  I  can't solve it the differential equation because of division by zero.

Comment: First find the solution of the homogeneous equation.

Comment: What is the expression you try to evaluate ?

Comment: It's written on question but I don't know why my LaTex doesn't looks good..

Comment: What did you get for $y_1$ and $y_2?$

Comment: I got $C_{1}*e^{2x} =y_{1}$ and 0=$y_{2}

Comment: OK.  There's the problem.  The roots of $r^2+4=0$ are $r=\pm 2i.$  You should have gotten $y_1=\cos 2x$ and $y_2 = \sin 2x.$

Comment: thank you very much if you can set it as an answer I will be so happy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auxillary equation is $r^2+4=0,$ with roots $r=0 \pm 2i.$ You should have gotten $y_1=e^{0x} \cos 2x$ and $y_2=e^{0x} \sin 2x.$ The Wronskian is then 
$$
W(y_1,y_2)=\det \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos 2x & \sin 2x  \\ -2\sin 2x & 2\cos 2x \end{array}\right] = 2\cos^2 2x + 2\sin^2 2x = \boxed{2}.
$$

Comment: how could you find $sin2x$ if value of beta is 0

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by beta.

Comment: when you write $2i$ it means $2i+0$ '2' is the alpha value and '0' is beta you have to product beta to the $x$ before use it on $sinu$ or $cosu$

Comment: that's exactly what makes my $y_{1}$ comes zero

Comment: See my edit above $(r=0 \pm 2i)$ and see @KevinZ solution below on how to use the wronskian to solve the problem above. You may be getting your "alpha" and "beta" backwards.

Answer (score 2):

Start by writing down the charactersitic equation of the associated homogeneous equation and solving for the roots.

$$m^2 + 4 = 0$$
$$m^2 = -4 = 4i^2$$

$m_1= 2i$ and $m_2=-2i$

Thus $y_h=c_1\cos2x +c_2\sin2x$

Now calculate the Wronskian and determine the particular solution.

$w= \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
    \cos(2x) & \sin(2x) \\
     -2\sin(2x) & 2\cos(2x)
  \end{array} \right] = 2\cos^2(2x)+2\sin^2(2x) = 2(\cos^2(2x)+ \sin^2(2x)) = 2 \times 1 = 2
$

$w_1= \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     0 & \sin(2x) \\
     3\csc(2x) & 2\cos(2x)
  \end{array} \right] = -3\csc(2x)\sin(2x) = -3\times\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(2x)} = -3
$

$w_2= \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     \cos(2x) & 0 \\
     -2\sin(2x) & 3\csc(2x)
  \end{array} \right] = 3\cos(2x)\csc(2x) = 3\times\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)} = 3\times{\cot(2x)}
$

Thus

$u_1'=\frac{w_1}{w} = \frac{-3}{2} \implies u_1= \frac{-3}{2}x  $

$u_2'= \frac{w_2}{w} = \frac{3}{2}\cot(2x) \implies u_2= \frac{3}{4}\ln|\sin(2x)|$

Then $$y = y_h + y_p = y_h + uy_1 + uy_2$$
$$y= c_1\cos(2x) +c_2sin(2x) - \frac{3}{2}x\cos(2x) +\frac{3}{4}\sin(2x)\ln|\sin(2x)|$$

Comment: wait a minute my problem is right in here $y_{h}$ (as far as I know) is $e^{ax}(c_{1}*sinB2x+c_{2}*cosB2x)$ which in our case $a=2$ and $B=0$ because the root is $2i+0$

Comment: The general solution of the associated homogeneous equation when you have complex conjugate roots is: $e^{\alpha{x}}[c_1cos\beta{x} + c_2sin\beta{x}]$

Comment: In our case, our root is of the form $\alpha + \beta{i}$ so $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta = \pm2$